# SQL Server Multiple LEFT JOIN, one-to-many

Tags: sql, join

I am looking for a way to perform multiple joins from one source table to more than one table. Similar to the following:

```
SELECT a.NAME, b.address, c.phone
FROM tblname a
LEFT JOIN tbladdress b ON a.nid = b.nid
```

I also want to perform a left join on the Telephone table `tblPhone` at the same time:

```
tblname a left join tblPhone c on a.PID = c.PID
```

Try as I might I can't see how to put this into one query.

Comment: If a name has 6 addresses and 5 phones associated what do you want the result to be? 30 rows with every permutation?

Comment: In this scenario the address and telephone are unique / one value each. Thanks all for your suggestions I got it working with RedFilter's answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply repeat your `JOIN` clauses as many times as is needed, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.NAME
    ,b.address
    ,c.phone
FROM tblname a
LEFT JOIN tbladdress b ON a.nid = b.nid
LEFT JOIN tblPhone c ON a.PID = c.PID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.name, b.address, c.phone 
FROM tblname a 
left join tbladdress b on a.nid = b.nid
left join tblPhone c on a.PID = c.PID;
```

Comment: Sky is the limit. Just don't go over 42 joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, b.address, c.phone 
FROM (tblname a 
  left join tbladdress b on a.nid = b.nid) c 
left join tblPhone d on c.PID=d.PID
```